# Performance of the SELECTs

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I need some help performing my SELECTs. I made an SQL fiddle to show you the database.

I need to perform two queries but they didn't work fine:

**First:**

```
SELECT  s.id, s.day_of_week, s.title
FROM slots s 
LEFT JOIN bookings_has_slots bhs
ON s.id = bhs.slot_id
LEFT JOIN bookings b
ON bhs.booking_id = b.id

WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT    null
  FROM  bookings_has_slots bhs2
  LEFT JOIN bookings b2
  ON        bhs2.booking_id = b2.id
  WHERE     b.date = '2018-01-27'
)
AND s.service_id = 3
AND s.day_of_week = DAYOFWEEK('2018-01-27');
```

**Returns:**

```
id  day_of_week title
3   7           Après-midi (14h30 - 17h00)
```

**But I expect:**
    no results, because the three slots possibilities for this day_of_week on the same date are taken.

**Second:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT b3.date AS unavailable_date
FROM bookings b3
LEFT JOIN bookings_has_slots bhs3
ON bhs3.booking_id = b3.id
LEFT JOIN slots s3
ON s3.id = bhs3.slot_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT    null
  FROM slots s 
  LEFT JOIN bookings_has_slots bhs
  ON s.id = bhs.slot_id
  LEFT JOIN bookings b
  ON bhs.booking_id = b.id

  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  null
    FROM    bookings_has_slots bhs2
    LEFT JOIN bookings b2   
    ON      bhs2.booking_id = b2.id
    WHERE   b.date = b2.date
  )
  AND s.service_id = 3
  AND s.day_of_week = s3.day_of_week
);
```

**Returns:**

```
unavailable_date
2018-01-17
2018-01-31
2018-01-27
2018-02-03
```

**But I expect:**

```
unavailable_date
2018-01-17
2018-01-31
2018-01-27
```

Because here, there are two others slots available for the "2018-02-03" not taken by any other bookings.

Here is the sql fiddle :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89e46/9

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: So what's your question? What is the current result, what do you need instead?

Comment: His question is to optimize the queries? AndyG and C-Otto

Comment: provide your data as sql fiddle you are almost there

Comment: stop posting such big portions of database set up, prepare sqlfiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Here is what I've made for you but check data part, for some reason it refuse to add your last data inserts http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4500f3

Comment: @C-Otto in the sql fiddle, my first query need to retrieve me only unavailable dates (date with no available slots)...but stil retrieve me some available dates. 
And my second query need to retrieve me only available slots (the ones not already booked), but with the example I gave, retrieve me a slot already booked

Comment: @AndyG Sorry I'm French, I change my post to explain my problem in a better way.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, I want to optimize my queries and to perform them well. I have some mistakes and I think it could be easier to obtain the results I want

Comment: @Alex I Check the data part and made a valid sql fiddle, but always need your help finding my solution.. Thanks

Comment: Check my Edit and put your expected result of 1st query. And add second query you have broken using same template I did for your 1st one

Comment: @Alex Thank you, I put my expected result. Trying to explain you the best way I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the answer yet.

But Could you confirm that this will fix your 1st query:

```
SELECT  s.id, s.day_of_week, s.title
FROM slots s 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT slot_id, booking_id
  FROM bookings_has_slots bhs
  INNER JOIN bookings b
  ON b.id = bhs.booking_id
    AND b.date = '2018-02-03'
  ) bhs
ON s.id = bhs.slot_id
WHERE s.day_of_week = DAYOFWEEK('2018-02-03')
  AND bhs.booking_id IS NULL;
```

2nd query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53a998/1

```
SELECT d.date unavailable_date, d.used_slots
FROM (
  SELECT b.date, COUNT(b.id) used_slots
  FROM bookings b
  GROUP BY b.date
  ) d
LEFT JOIN slots s 
ON  s.day_of_week = DAYOFWEEK(d.date)
GROUP BY d.date
HAVING d.used_slots = COUNT(s.id);
```

Comment: When I change the date with '2018-02-03' which have only one booking on 3 available slots , it give me no results whereas it should provide me the 2 others available slots..

Comment: Cant get your data structure. Can you provide query to get all slots available and not available for 2018-02-03?

Comment: Aren't you able to get the structure on this sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89e46/33 ?

Comment: There is jut MY query which you complain about not bringing expected result. I ask to provide query which will return all slots for specific date and then I want to understand what do you mean by "available" and unavailable.

Comment: You also have the Schema and the INSERTs on the left panel, don't you?

Comment: yes I have form your post, but I can't understand the logic behind. and since you do not provide the quesry I ask for - looks like you have no answer

Comment: I don't have the query you ask. 
By available I mean that a slot is for a specific day of week, and available once a day. So when a slot is taken on a specific date, only others slots with the same day of week will be available, and with the good service_id which is in the slots table in my schema

Comment: It's a booking system. People can book for a service, but for example, a service is only available Wednesday Morning, Saturday Morning and Saturday afternoon. So when selecting a date (which have available slots , that's why I need to query for the unavailable dates to disable them), I want to let the user choose between the available slots , on this specific date they selected before

Comment: `bookings_has_slots` seem absolutely weird to me. what do you store there?

Comment: Yes this is all slots for the specific date

Comment: I create `bookings_has_slots` because certain services will have the possibility to book all day, so I will have to assign all day slots to a specific booking.

Comment: Thanks !! It seems to be perfect for this query !

Comment: We just need to add a clause "where s.service_id = :id" to precise the service, and to be sure to have the appropriate slots

Comment: So I confirm that this will fix my 1st query !

Comment: Do you think my database is well designed or it could be better and that's why it's difficult ?

Comment: yes, something is wrong with your database. for example for the last query we need to create a subquery just to get list of dates - that is bad. An both queries I posted a far from performance ones. probably I would start from creating table with dates and slots. from your point of view that could be unneccesary. but if you would have initial table `id, date, slot_id` everything becomes much simpler I guess. and you can fill this table every week or every month when start

Comment: I understand well what you are saying but don't really know where to begin and how to change that. Just because I wanted to let the admin add, modify or delete some slots, the only solution I've found was to use the day_of_week. I don't already look on how to fill a table automatically every week, month, year.

Comment: And as you can see in my fiddle, I've made a calendar_table, with `date, day_of_week`, and lot of information on 100 years. I used to think it will help me but can't find the solution

Comment: Think about this idea from this point of view: you give possibility to add slot to some Admin. Today he add new slot (for example for Monday), and some other admin run the report about last week and sees that we did not use Monday for 100% load. But he ran same report yesterday and that report showed 100% load for last monday. Do you see my point? right now everything is too dynamic. Try to imagine that somebody removed the slot, which was already booked? what will happen with all your queries?

Comment: Sorry, I can explain everything in SO format :-) you need to learn yourself. Just put your efforts :-) step by step

Comment: Oh okay.. that’s why it would be better to assign a slot to the next x weeks/months. Thanks you very much for your help and your good advices to keep going on :-)